# How to request Prometheus percentage instead of count?

Tags: prometheus

I use Graphana do display data from Prometheus. I have request to display quantity of "failed" events (I mean success="false"):

```
count(test{deviceserial=~"$device",branch=~"$branch",
   class=~"$class",build_id=~"$build_id",success="false"}) by (deviceserial)
```

How to request/display percentage of failed instead of absolute value?

Answer (score 2):

````
count by (deviceserial) (test{deviceserial=~"$device",branch=~"$branch",
        class=~"$class",build_id=~"$build_id",success="false"})
  /
count by (deviceserial) (test{deviceserial=~"$device",branch=~"$branch",
        class=~"$class",build_id=~"$build_id"})```
````

Note the missing `success="false"` from the second selector. I'm assuming here you have a metric `test` with the listed labels and particularly `success="true"` when the test succeeds and `success="false"`when it fails.

Comment: Dividing a number by itself will always end up with 1. For example: 1 / 1 = 1.

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful comment. Also, dividing a number by a different number will always end up with a value different from 1. For example 1 / 2 = 0.5. Your point?

Comment: It is not. If you'll look more closely you'll notice the two selectors are not in fact identical. This computes the ratio of "failed" events (see the `success="false"` matcher in the first expression) to all events (no filter by `success` in the second expression).